# multiple versions of a defaulted special member functions are not allowed (MSVC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Is this a valid C++ code:

```
struct S
{
    S(S const&) = default;
    S(S&) = default;
};
```

?

**Context:**

I tried to deal with ambiguity in following code by adding these two lines to `S` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j9znrY6ef)):

```
#include <utility>


struct Inner
{
    Inner(int);
};

struct Outer
{
    //Outer(Outer const&) = default;
    //Outer(Outer&) = default;

    template<class T>
    Outer(T&& inner) : inner_(std::forward<T>(inner)) {}

    Inner inner_;
};

auto foo()
{
    auto v1 = Outer(1);
    Outer v2 = v1;
    return v2.inner_;
}
```

Uncommenting two lines in `S` makes GCC happy, but MSVC produces error C2580. Question is -- is MSVC correct or not?

The error for the above `S` is:

```
<source>(8): error C2580: 'S::S(S &)': multiple versions of a defaulted special member functions are not allowed
```

Comment: Is the second one supposed to be `Outer(Outer&&) = default;`?

Comment: please post the code that has the error you want to fix. And include the error message in the question. I also dont understand what ambiguity you want to fix by those two lines, without them the problem is missing conversion from `Outer` to `Inner`

Comment: @tkausl No, it is specifically `Outer(Outer&) = default;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number question is about validity of that tiny snippet. Context is provided only if you are interested why I am asking this.

Comment: @rafix07 But I did "provide" two implementations of copy constructor -- is it permitted by standard?

Comment: It's a note so it's non-normative text, but it appears MSVC is wrong here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#copy.ctor-note-1.  I'm trying to find that actual text that the note sumarizes.

Comment: fyi under investigation since  Feb 25, 2019 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-c2580-multiple-versions-of-a-defaulted-speci/468431

Comment: but this tiny snippet requires me to remove the `//` from the two lines, or not? I am really not sure about which version of the code the question is about. If we are supposed to remove the `//` why dont you do it?

Comment: ok I think now I get it. Your question is about `S` and for that struct gcc produces no error and msvc does produce an error. Why not include the error in the question? That would be useful context

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Error code and text is included if you read it carefully :). And if you click on godbolt link -- you'll see all details.

Comment: I dont get why the discussion. Questions about errors in code should contain the error message in the question. In the same time you refuse in comments you could have added it