# std::alignment_union for a lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++14

This is a follow up question to : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088723/stdfunction-with-static-allocation-in-c) - replacing an  `std::function` with a non-allocating one , that does not use `std` .

Was wondering if there is something more robust that can replace: `std::aligned_union`

```
 typedef unsigned char callable_array[100];
 typename std::aligned_union<0, callable_array, CallableT<void(*)()>, CallableT<void (CallableT<void(*)()>::*)()>>::type callable_;
```

The suggested code to do that is causing an compilation error

```
CallableT<decltype([]()->void {})>, // error: lambda expression in an unevaluated operand
```

trying both c++11 and c++14

It also uses `std::max` - was hoping for some ideas on how to replace it as well.

Edit: my example that shows compilation error : [Example that don't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5fzhraqEd)

Comment: "*It also uses std::max - was hoping for some ideas on how to replace it as well.*" I can understand wanting to avoid `std::function`'s allocations, but `max` doesn't allocate. Is there some reason to avoid it?

Comment: The question you linked has an answer with a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/w2cEaq) link, is that not good enough? Uses placement new, no allocations. Lambda parameter also compiles.

Comment: I have built a small example using the linked code, It wont compile.
(edited the example into  the question)

Comment: I am working on an embedded system with restrictions

Comment: Add `static auto MakeLambda() { return []()->void {}; }` to the class, and use `decltype(MakeLambda())` where you need the lambda type. [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/336TEoczo). It's unclear though why you think the size or alignment of that lambda type is indicative of anything. Clearly a lambda that captures a large object by value can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thanks, should I better use "etl::uninitialized_buffer" from : https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl/blob/master/include/etl/memory.h

Comment: Also this "hack" to tell how many bytes were allocated? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163607/avoid-memory-allocation-with-stdfunction-and-member-function